# Raspberry Pi Robotics: How to follow line?

Tags: gpio, python

I'm making a raspberry pi robot in Python and it moves, but it does not follow the line and I am using an infrared line sensor. I think that I have done everything properly.

Here are some results by replacing 0 and 0 (in the expressions) to different values (00, 01, 10, 11) and I've got some results here:

> `00` - Circles with boosts
>   `10` - Circles with boosts
>   `01` - Circles with boosts
>   `11` - Straight line
>   `10` with no DRIVE_1 - Circles

I've narrowed it down to these lines of code and I think that it's an infinite loop problem:

```
    if line_left == 0:
        GPIO.output(DRIVE_1, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(DRIVE_2, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
        RobotForward()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    elif line_right == 0:
        GPIO.output(DRIVE_1, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(DRIVE_2, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        RobotForward()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        RobotForward()
```

Robot from front side:
[image: Front]

Robot from back side:
[image: Back]

Robot from left side:
[image: Left]

Robot from right side:
[image: Right]

Robot from above:
[image: Above]

Robot from below:
[image: Below]

Comment: Do you have a way of confirming what it is actually doing at any given point?  You might want to attach a few leds (one for right and one for left) and turn them on and off at the beginning and end of each block in the if/elsif.

Comment: I am not familiar with the method you are using.  I've only ever used two sensors which are positioned slightly further apart than the width of the black line to be followed.  Then its straight on if both sensors see white, left if right hand sensor sees black, right if left hand sensor sees black, random if both see black.

Comment: Is this your own robot design or are you following something posted on the Internet?